# TaskQueue POST request with a file or byte[] as parameter (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, playframework

Is it possible to invoke a taskqueue with a parameter of a different type then String?
My code currently looks like this but the code in the queue is never reached: (Playframework coding)

```
public static void addOrUpdateShops(byte[] xmlFile) {
  checkUserExists();
  QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().add(withUrl("/DataTransferController/addOrUpdateShopz").param( "xmlFile", xmlFile).method(TaskOptions.Method.POST));
  renderText("Added to queue");
}

public static void addOrUpdateShopz(byte[] xmlFile) throws Exception {
  Logger.debug("Running queue task (addOrUpdateShopszz)");
  ShopModelUtilities.addShops(xmlFile);
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Use [`TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(byte[], String)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.Builder.html#withPayload%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) or on existing [`TaskOptions.payload(byte[], String)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.html#payload%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 3):

[Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9722071/752918) is correct, but in addition, you could not send a POST request with both payload and param defined. Attempting to set both values at the same time would trigger:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    Message body and parameters may not both be present; 
    only one of these may be supplied
```

Based on your code example, you must remove the `.param( "xmlFile", xmlFile)` from the builder chain of your TaskOption if you want to send byte[] payload on your TaskQueue request.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it's HTTP so only strings are passed through. The long answer is yes, you can serialize an object and then use an ObjectInputStream to read it and convert it back to an object but you have to do that manually or use something like Jersey (jax-rs) or a json reader to automatically deserialize it back to an object.

Comment: Http can transfer binary just fine - for example images.

Comment: Ah, a POST. You are correct. So you would need to either do as you recommend above or send the content as multi-part as you would a file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Look at calling a deferred function -- lots more payload flexibility. Remember a straight call to a TQ has a 10k limit which you may hit quickly if your payload is something like a jpeg.
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html

Comment: The limit is actually 100k and AFAIK it also applies to DeferredTask: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push.html#Quotas_and_Limits_for_Push_Queues

Comment: Unless something has changed recently, the limit as per the docs link provided is stated as "Task Queue items are limited to 10kb of associated data". There is an easy work around to the deferred strict limit achievable by using an entity. Entity limits are one meg. When doing deferred calls, you can easily check the entity payload size by trying to save it to memcache which has the same limit. If memcache write fails, you know the deferred call will fail also. A very good link expanding on deferred call exists beyond the GAE docs, but I don't have time to track it down.

Comment: Hmm, true. But in the docs say: `No need to panic, though: If you try to enqueue a task that is too big to fit on the queue by itself, the deferred library will automatically create a new Entity in the datastore to hold information about the task, and will delete the entity once the task has been run. This means that in practice, your function call can be up to 1MB once serialized.`

Comment: Right, I think I noted that in my second comment, but had forgotten the immediate conversion. Thanks.